# I use ManagementClass to run a Process, but I want that process to run in Background instead of UI console

Tags: c#, .net, process, background, console

I'm using Mangement class to create a process, but That starts a UI console - I want to console to run in background.

```
 public uint LaunchProcess(string sIPAddress, string sPort)
        {
            uint iPid = 0;
            try
            {
                logger.AddLog("LaunchProcess : " + sIPAddress + " " + sPort);
                object[] PlugInRunnerInfo = { StaticUtils.GetLocation(AgilentPluginCommonConstants.PlugInRunnerPath) + "\\" + "PlugInRunner.exe" + " " + sIPAddress + " " + sPort, null, null, 0 };

                //ManagementClass is a part of Windows Management Intrumentation,namespaces. One of its use is to provides access to manage applications.
                //Here this class is used to launch PlugInRunner as detached process.By setting the ManagementClass object's property 'CreateFlags' to value 0x00000008
                //we can start the PlugInRunner as detached one.
                using (var mgmtObject = new ManagementClass("Win32_Process"))
                {
                   
                    var processStartupInfo = new ManagementClass("Win32_ProcessStartup",null);
                    



                    processStartupInfo.Properties["CreateFlags"].Value = 0x00000008;//DETACHED_PROCESS.
                    var result = mgmtObject.InvokeMethod("Create", PlugInRunnerInfo);
                    if (result != null)
                    {
                        logger.AddLog("Process id " + Convert.ToUInt32(PlugInRunnerInfo[3]));
                        iPid = Convert.ToUInt32(PlugInRunnerInfo[3]);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                logger.AddLog("Exception " + ex.Message);
            }
            return iPid;
        }
```

The above code what I have got. Please help me.

Comment: Why don't you use [Process.Start](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.start)?

Comment: sorry for confusion , its not written by me. I'm intern, if you could please help me out how its done - i will learn abou it or if you know how we can do in management class

Comment: Did you try tp set the ShowWindow property of [Win32_ProcessStartup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-processstartup)?

Comment: sorry to disappoint Idk how to.

Comment: Something like `processStartupInfo["ShowWindow"] = 0;`?

Comment: it didn't work, the console window opened up again. How do we implement process.start?